# How to send http body data on an ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, http

```
$(document).delegate('form', 'submit', function(event) {
var $form = $(this);
var id = $form.attr('id');
// ...
  /* stop form from submitting normally */
  event.preventDefault();

//   /* get the action attribute from the <form action=""> element */
   var $form = $(this),
   url = $form.attr( 'action' );    

   var timeId = parseInt(id.substring(11));

   var formData = new FormData($("#"+id)[0]);
   console.log("time id of form is "+timeId);
   console.log(formData);
   $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(result){},
    error: function(er){}
    });

});
```

I am sending the image file from a html form using ajax post. How can i send additional data as a body of this http post

Comment: Your `formData` will have all form inputs serialized, just put some hidden fields to pass it as additional information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass the additional data from the DOM elements, you can use the `serialize()` as well.

```
$('form#id').serialize();
```

If you want to get the images, you should go with like this.

```
console.log($('#image').get(0).files[0]);

<input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" id="image">
```

Multiple files can be appended by using each

```
var data = new FormData();
$.each($('#image')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('file-'+i, file);
});
```

Pass addition data in formData

```
data.append("timeId",10000);
```

```js
//Program a custom submit function for the form
$("form#test").submit(function(event){
  //disable the default form submission
  event.preventDefault();
  //Other data
  console.log($(this).serialize());
  //File data
  console.log($('#image').get(0).files);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="test" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="10">
  
  <input type="file" name="file" id="image">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: OP asks how to put additional info to `formData` variable, not how to access DOM elements...

Comment: Yes, i want to know how to put additional info to the format variable

Comment: @Justinas He asked to send image files as well, please check the question. I've added few more information on the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i am relatively new to javascript, so can you tell me how i can access the < input type="hidden" name="id" value="10"> on the server, does it come as part of the body of the http request

Comment: Did you check ? is everthing ok ?

Comment: I have seen the working example and the id, values are present in the URL,but since i am submitting the form with an image i am using var formData = new FormData($("#"+id)[0]);                                                          and sending the data as an an ajax post request. can you please help me out as to how i can access the name="id" on the server ? does it appear as a param, , thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124273/discussion-between-user3655266-and-loading).

Comment: @Justinas Please reverse your downvote, as I've helped the questioner and provided all the required information to solve his issue.